# Extract highest date per month from a list of dates

Tags: postgresql

I have a `date` column which I am trying to query to return only the largest date per month.

What I currently have, albeit very simple, returns 99% of what I am looking for. For example, If I list the column in ascending order the first entry is `2016-10-17` and ranges up to `2017-10-06`.

A point to note is that the last day of every month may not be present in the data, so I'm really just looking to pull back whatever is the "largest" date present for any existing month.

The query I'm running at the moment looks like

```
SELECT MAX(date_col)
  FROM schema_name.table_name
 WHERE <condition1>
   AND <condition2>
 GROUP BY EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_col)
 ORDER BY max;
```

This does actually return most of what I'm looking for - what I'm actually getting back is

```
"2016-11-30"
"2016-12-30"
"2017-01-31"
"2017-02-28"
"2017-03-31"
"2017-04-28"
"2017-05-31"
"2017-06-30"
"2017-07-31"
"2017-08-31"
"2017-09-29"
"2017-10-06"
```

which are indeed the maximal values present for every month in the column. However, the result set doesn't seem to include the maximum date value from October 2016 (The first months worth of data in the column). There are multiple values in the column for that month, ranging up to `2016-10-31`.

If anyone could point out why the max value for this month isn't being returned, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: You're grouping by month only, not year and month. So since there's a "2017-10-06" value, that is greater than a "2016-10-nn" value.

Comment: Thanks for the response @eurotrash. That fixed it alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping by month (1 to 12) rather than by month and year. Since `2017-10-06` is greater than any day in October 2016, that's what you get for the "October" group.

You should

```
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', date_col)
```

Comment: Yep, that was the issue alright. Many thanks for the prompt response.